# Test method threw exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to parse multiple parameters in Json to a RESTful service using Webclient in C#. I keep an error of 400 bad request. It works when i pass one parameter but does not work when i try to pass multiple, please advise: The below code is in my Test Methjod to query the RESTful endpoint

```
        AuthToken = GetAuthToken();
        var wcProxy = new WebClient();
        wcProxy.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + AuthToken;
        wcProxy.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
        wcProxy.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

        var vm = new ValidateBankAccountCriteria
            {
                AccountNumber = "62294444915",
                BankAccountType = BankAccountType.CurrentAccount,
                BranchCode = "254605"
            };

        string payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
        var payloaded = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload);

        Byte[] returnData = wcProxy.UploadData(new Uri(wsUrl + "ValidateBankAccount/"), "POST", payloaded);

        var results = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(returnData);
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Contains("NEDBANK"), "call failed");
```

Comment: does your rest method accept multiple params?

Comment: What do you mean by "one parameter"? One instance of `ValidateBankAccountCriteria`? What are you passing in the other case? A `List<ValidateBankAccountCriteria>`?Are you in control of both ends?

Comment: @rdoubleui I think you are right. If it works with a single object it will not work with a list of objects since this would be another type for the server methods. If you want to do that ( and are in control of both ends ) always use a list

Comment: the method accepts one instnace of ValidateBankAccountCriteria but obvioulsy this is a class with 3 properties, - everytime i pass this through - it failes with an error 400 bad request